# How to simplify terms with usage of square root in maxima

Tags: maxima, simplification

Let's say we have a term like `1/4 * x/sqrt(2) * x^2 / 2;` in Maxima. 
As an output (without further modification) it gives `x^3/2^(7/2)`.
How can I force the output format to be like `x^3/(8*sqrt(2))` with usage of square roots whenever possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
(%i1) sq2: " "(sqrt(2))$
(%i2) matchdeclare(n, lambda([n], oddp(n) and n#1))$
(%i3) defrule(r_sq2, 2^(n/2), sq2*2^((n-1)/2))     $
(%i4) e: 1/4 * x/sqrt(2) * x^2 / 2;
                                       3
                                      x
(%o4)                                ----
                                      7/2
                                     2
(%i5) apply1(e, r_sq2);
                                             3
                                  (sqrt(2)) x
(%o5)                            -------------
                                      16
```

A rule can help to insert `sqrt(2)`. In the example I use a "null" function to prevent simplification. You can also consider `box` and `rembox` functions or leave `sq2` undefined.

Comment: Works fine for the example with sqrt(2). Is there also a generic approach for all sqrt(int)?